# jquery: restarting gif animation not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, gif, animated-gif

I have animated gif on my website and sometimes I need to restart it.

when I need to restart the animation I use:

```
    $('#animatedGif').attr('src', "");
    $('#animatedGif').attr('src', srcToGif);
```

And it works perfectly in every browser except Firefox (FF 4.0 under windows, under linux it works even in FF). Any ideas how to run it under FF?

Comment: I do it the same way and it works in firefox. which version do you have and have you tried disabling some extensions?

Comment: Under windows I have FF 4.0 without any extensions. Under ubuntu I have FF 3.6.16 and it works fine.

Comment: One workaround idea would be replace the image element by a newly created one.

Comment: Another possible workaround would be `$x.removeAttr('src').attr('src', srcToGif)`. Maybe it will work, maybe not.

Comment: @ mu is too short - unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: @Pekka, your workaround is also not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strangely, unlike for you, it works for me in FF4 on Windows with no extensions loaded.

Maybe the problem is elsewhere?

Anyway, if you're ready to force a reload, adding a constantly changing parameter to the image URL should *always* work:

```
 $('#animatedGif').attr('src', srcToGif+"?"+new Date().getTime());
```

**Edit:** Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jvqQY/1/

Try resetting the first image: You will see that both images get reset. It proves that animation state seems to be cached *for the entire resource* and not just a specific image element. That is weird!

Comment: Great! That works, as far as I got it checked. It works a little bit weird in IE but "go to hell IE" :P And you're right, it is weird that the state is cached... Interesting

Comment: @Gacek yeah, that's strange. The link pointed to a broken fiddle btw, it is now fixed.